# Migrate to new SQL Server 2017 on linux

Tags: sql-server, linux, sql-server-2017, sql-server-on-linux

I have SQL CLR functions in my SQL Server 2016, if I'd migrate it to SQL Server 2017 on Linux. How to handle those functions? As I know that SQL CLR relies on .NET framework and AFAIK that .NET is not that well cross-platformed.

Comment: FYI. Since SQL Server 2017, there's a specific SQL Server edition for Linux. So please stop removing the specific tag [sql-server-on-linux].

Answer (score 1):

.Net core is cross-platform. I would assume 2017 would be using libraries from .Net core and not the regular .Net framework. .Net framework is build only for windows whereas .Net core is built for cross-platform. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/articles/core/getting-started